# How to use preg_replace

Tags: preg-replace, substr

I have a String:

```
    $str= "(and marque:'Mercedes Benz' model:'F Type')";
```

I want to return string like this:

```
    $str2= "(and marque:'Mercedes-Benz' model:'F-Type')";
```

so, I want to replace space with '-' char but only between '' chars.

Should I use preg_replace function?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str= "(and marque:'Mercedes Benz' model:'F Type')";
$str = preg_replace("/'(\w+)\s+/","'$1-", $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
(and marque:'Mercedes-Benz' model:'F-Type')
```