# How to use preg_replace?

Tags: php

how to get specific text of variable using preg_replace:

```
$text = "hello micle, your transaction id 1313xxx success. SN: 525252xxx. your balance is $10 @18/08 14:14:51#";
```

than I need `preg_replace` return `id : 1313xx, success status, SN, and balance.`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727284/how-to-use-preg-replace

Comment: Do you need values or the string that you have placed `id : 1313xx, success status, SN, and balance.`

Comment: 1313 and 525252 are hard coded or are arbitrary numbers? "x" is any character? Plus we would be pleased, if you showed us what did you try to solve the problem.

Comment: PHP has one of the best manuals available imo. quick google and - [voila](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) -  a whole page on `preg_replace()`

Comment: Yes, I need that frag_replace return value of ID, success status, SN, and Balance

Comment: Sounds like you want the values, so use preg_match. Unless you're actually trying to REPLACE text, you don't want to be using preg_replace.

Comment: id return any character, sn return number

Comment: Read the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

This one will be helpful to you .

```
$specified_txt="Arun";
if(stripos($specified_txt,$specified_txt)!==false)
{
    $string = 'Hi Arun How Are You';
    $pattern = '/'.$specified_txt.'/';
    $replacement = 'Sarvanan';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
}

echo "<br>";

$string = 'php mysql jquery javascript xml html css ajax.';
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/php/';
$patterns[1] = '/mysql/';
$patterns[2] = '/jquery/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'Java';
$replacements[1] = 'sql';
$replacements[0] = 'AngularJs';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```